# Why setting permission in Spatie\Permission hav invalid model_type value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

In  Laravel 8 app I set permission to user with control:

```
public function store( $user_id )
{

    $request = request();
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $permission_id= $requestData['permission_id'];
    $permission= Permission::find($permission_id);
    $user= Permission::find($user_id);

    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        \Log::info(  varDump($permission->name, ' -1 $permission->name::') );
        $user->givePermissionTo($permission->name); // Valid permission name
        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();

        return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    return response()->json(['message' => ''], HTTP_RESPONSE_OK);
}
```

It is added, but model_type has ‘Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission’, not ‘App\Models\User’ as I
expected, so Permission does not work properly...

How correctly ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
Making init seeding like:

```
$editAdPermission = Permission::create(['name' => PERMISSION_EDIT_AD, 'guard_name' => 'web']);
$adsEditorRole->givePermissionTo($editAdPermission); // means : adsEditor can edit ad
$editAdUser= User::find(1);
if ( $editAdUser ) {
    $editAdUser->givePermissionTo($editAdPermission);
    $editAdUser->givePermissionTo($deleteAdPermission);
}
```

I have many rows with model_type == ‘App\Models\User’ : https://prnt.sc/wstzqk
Also row with model_type == ‘Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission’ is not in collection returned by
$user->getPermissionNames() . I think because of wrong model_type value.

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't get the problem. Can you explain about what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: Have your customized the models in *config/permission.php*?

Comment: No, I left it default. What have I to modify?

Comment: No. It's ok. Have you added `HasRoles` trait to App\Models\User?

Comment: Yes, I added HasRoles  trait in App\Models\User